# Is output of fast-forward and --no-ff merge same?

Tags: git, git-merge

Please consider the following git branches:

[image]

If we type the command `git merge feature`, git does a fast forward merge and basically moves the **master** pointer to **feature** pointer, but the files will keep the data from **Feature** commit.

But if i type command `git merge --no-ff feature`, git will do a merge with no fast-forward condition and will create a new merge commit, but here too the files will keep the data from **Feature** commit.
.

Both these merge changes the branch in a different way. However, the output of both type of merge always seems to be same with files stored on disk being same as they were in **Feature** commit.

My questions are:

- Will the output of both fast-forward merge and no fast-forward merge be always same in terms of files stored in working directory?
- Also, can a `--no-ff merge` cause merge conflicts in cases like these when there is a direct linear path from the source branch to the target branch?

Comment: Yes, the file contents are the same. The only change is to the commit history that leads to the file contents. A merge conflict is not possible because the three-way merge is merging two identical trees, and a tree cannot conflict with itself.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're going to get a better answer than @RaymondChen's comment. I'd propose that either that comment becomes the answer, or perhaps this question is a dup of another, though a quick search isn't turning up anything that addresses the differences between the ff and --no-ff, and includes the add-ons that the *state* is the same and conflicts aren't possible. These questions are related, but IMHO not quite dups: [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9069061/184546) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6701292/184546).

Comment: It's in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70715962/902497) to "Proper way to merge dev into main branch": "whether you allow fast-forward to occur, or if you use --no-ff to force creating a merge commit, the resulting file structure is identical."

Comment: @RaymondChen Agreed, and I closed it as a dup. (Funny side note, I wrote that answer and forgot about it...)

Comment: @TTT Haha, I hadn't even noticed it was your answer!